# more secure? select/update from postgresql table

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

i have 4 users ... or even more - they works in custom companys.

Table A:

```
userName | companyName
---------|-------------
user1    | co1
-----------------------
user2    | co2
------------------------
...
```

And i have a lot of some tables:
tableB - with products, tableC with something else other... many, many tables.
Eeach table has a column called: companyName.

My questions:
Question 1: how to write?/exec a function to  select/update/insert varoius variable-sized questions, so that each user can read/write update only records with own companyName.

I (think I )could use:

```
 select * from tableC, userName, companyName from tableA ..... where   tableC.companyName=tableA.companyName and tableA.userName=currentuser();
```

but what if some of users make a query (from PGAdmin or something like):

```
select * from tableC;
```

Question 2a:I would like to block this possibility on server level.
Question 2b: Is it any way to write function (each one for insert/update/delete query) for unknown list of arguments?

Question 2c:How to add full access for tableA...to TableX for this written function only, independ on executing  user?

Comment: you are looking for https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-rowsecurity.html

Comment: Yes, yes, yes this is IT!

Comment: Thank You @vao tsun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-rowsecurity.html

> row security policies that restrict, on a per-user basis, which rows
>   can be returned by normal queries or inserted, updated, or deleted by
>   data modification commands. This feature is also known as Row-Level
>   Security. By default, tables do not have any policies, so that if a
>   user has access privileges to a table according to the SQL privilege
>   system, all rows within it are equally available for querying or
>   updating.

and as example

```
 CREATE POLICY user_policy ON users
    USING (true)
    WITH CHECK (user_name = current_user);
```

will make select result to contain only rows where column user_name is equal to current_user